# Tips on developing EMR system

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, vb.net, web-applications

We are asked to develop an EMR system. But we are not fully knowledgeable about the coverage of an EMR. Any tips on how we are going to start this project? And we have decided to use ASP.NET and SQL.

Comment: this question is not a good fit for this site as it is too broad - which is why you have received downvotes and close votes, but you have been lucky to receive two good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer this question generic way

- "Project" itself is a temporary entity, it means if you are going to start a project , there must be some delivery date and there must be requirements. focus on that.
- Then decide the project you are going to do, and think of your capabilities, don't do something you can't accomplish. Be specific.
- Make sure that everybody’s expectations are clear. its not only, it also involves Version control repository (SVN recommended),Continuous integration, testing, QA etc
- Always monitor your progress, This will be based on the methodology (like agile)

This is the basic, in your EMR project

- Gather the requirements ( its very important, if you don't know what to do no one can help you)
- Make a plan
- Go for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume by EMR you mean Electronic Medical Record?

Be wary. 
1) This is an area related to health, and, as such, is probably littered with administrative and legislative pitfalls that you need to be aware of (liability can be a big problem).
There will be concerns about
- data protection
- data traceability, authentication...
- data exchange with existing systems
- liability on bugs that might lead to a medical error

2) There is a big amount of medical-technobabble you will need to understand, as well as a big amount of implicit standard procedures in the medical area. Be prepared to spend a lot of time with the end-users. They will not have a lot of time for you, as their job is a very demanding one, and they might not have a lot of understanding for you not knowing their habits and language.

Point 2 is, arguably, something that comes up with every project, but if your expertise is far from this subject, it might come back and bite you.
This is probably a good candidate for an agile release-early/often cycle otherwise you WILL end up delivering an unusable system.

From the top of my head, this is what I can see. I would not advise using stackoverflow as the source of information on what is an EMR though... there are bound to be better sources. Maybe a little more discussion with your client first, backed by reading at least a few of the documents referenced by the  [wikipedia EMR page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_medical_record).

All in all, your question seems to show that you might not envision the complexity of the task, and all its dangers.
Yes, at the end of the day it is just another data management system with a few quirks, but it is in a very sensitive area, so be careful and think hard, or dig a little, before taking on the project. Do some research...

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciated your comment. Yes, I know the dangers and the complexity of the system that we are about to create so we'll do our best to strictly plan our system. Thanks for the advise!

Comment: I'm sorry if it came out as condecending. Re-reading my answer it seems a bit harsh, not knowing you. All my good wishes in your project anyway.